# Check if .dll file exists and load it

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, dll, dllimport

What is the easiest want to check if a .dll file exists, then to load it ? ( i don't need to use modules from that dll file, i just want to run it ).

I'd like to have simple example of code.

Comment: Are you trying to use an unmanaged dll or a managed one? I'm assuming unmanaged because of the dllimport tag, although VB.NET has the `Declare` statement.

Answer (score 3):

To check if a file exists use `system.io.file.exists(path)`.
To load the assembly look at `Assembly.Load`,  you can execute code from it by loading it, then calling `Activator.CreateInstance` on a  type from that assembly.  Once you have an instance of the type you can call methods on it.

If you don't have an interface defined on the type from the assembly for easy calling you will have to use Reflection to inspect the types and methods on those types.  That starts getting more complicated and without a specific example of what you are trying to do I can't give you an example of how to actually do it in code.

**updated example**

The simplest way to just execute code from a dynamically loaded assembly involves knowing a few things about it in advance.

You should know in advance the name of the `Type` that contains the code you want to execute, the name of the Method that contains the code, and the parameters it takes.  For this example lets say that you always have a class in the assembly called "MyClass", and the code you want to run is in a sub called "Execute" that take no parameters.  You can load and execute it like this.

You should Import `System.Reflection`

```
Dim asm as Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("TheDll.dll") 'Load the assembly
dim t as type = asm.GetType("MyClass") 'Get a reference to the type that contains the code
dim info as MethodInfo = t.GetMethod("Execute") 'Get a reference to the method on the type that we want to call
dim instance as object = Activator.CreateInstance(t) 'Create an instance of the type to call the method on
info.Invoke(obj,nothing) 'Invoke the method with no parameters
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to include hacking prevent system (a .dll file) into my VB application. a simple .dll file, I just need to load it, to let it work. that's it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a "simple" way of executing code from an assembly.

Comment: I just noticed your "dllimport" tag in the question.  If your question involves executing unmanaged code from a non-.net dll then my answer won't apply.  It's only for executing code from a managed assembly.

Comment: thanks all, I don't need to execute code from an assembly, I just want to load the dll. it does all the things by itself, I don't have to work with it after load. Thanks.